# PHP 5.3.3 - Mysql extensions not loading

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I keep getting the message "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress".

I installed `httpd`, `php` (5.3.3), `php-mysql`, `mysql` (5.1.73), `mysql-server` via `yum` install on RHEL6.

I tried uncommenting `extension=mysql.so` and restarting `httpd`, but that didn't do the trick.

On other nodes I don't have any issues after the same way of installing.

I see that the extensions are not loaded:

```
Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre [6] => zlib [7] => bz2 [8] => calendar [9] => ctype [10] => hash [11] => filter [12] => ftp [13] => gettext [14] => gmp [15] => SPL [16] => iconv [17] => Reflection [18] => session [19] => standard [20] => shmop [21] => SimpleXML [22] => sockets [23] => exif [24] => tokenizer [25] => xml [26] => apache2handler )
```

Anyone an idea why the extensions are not loaded/loading?

Comment: Is PHP running as an apache module, and therefore requiring a restart for changes to take effect?

Comment: Yes it is. Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
I restarted the httpd service after every change/ adjustment.

Comment: I also already installed the gd, mcrypt en mbstring components,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing php v5.6, see the link below:
https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/